# applying mean to a list after weighting

Tags: r

I have a list named `df` which contains three iterations with two years of projection.

What I want is:  weighting the variable `"district"` just for year 2 in each iteration and finally I want to have mean of each weighted district for all three iterations. Note that each year has a variable named `"weight"` that weighting should be based on this variable.

```
iteration1 <- list(year1 = data.frame(age = c(10, 11, 12, 13),
                                      district = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                                      gender = c(1, 2, 2, 1),
                                      weight = c(12.2, 11.3, 11.2, 10.1)),
                   year2 = data.frame(age = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 10, 10),
                                      district = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1),
                                      gender = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1),
                                      weight = c(12.2, 11.3, 11.2, 10.1, 12.2, 13.1)))

iteration2 <- list(year1 = data.frame(age = c(10, 11, 12, 13), 
                                      district = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                                      gender = c(2, 2, 1, 1),
                                      weight = c(12.2, 11.3, 11.2, 10.1)),
                   year2 = data.frame(age = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 13, 12),
                                      district = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3),
                                      gender = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                                      weight = c(12.2, 11.3, 11.2, 10.1, 10.9, 11.9, 15.1)))

iteration3 <- list(year1 = data.frame(age = c(10, 11, 12, 13),
                                      district = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                                      gender = c(2, 2, 1, 1),
                                      weight = c(12.2, 11.3, 11.2, 10.1)),
                   year2 = data.frame(age = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 10, 10, 11, 12),
                                      district = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2),
                                      gender = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2),
                                      weight = c(12.2, 11.3, 11.2, 10.1, 13.5, 12.8, 13.9, 14.9)))

df <- list(iteration1 = iteration1, iteration2 = iteration2, iteration3 = iteration3)
```

Expected output:

```r
district     mean of each district for all three iterations
1                           20.2          
2                           24.96 
3                           24.46
4                           14.6
```

for calculating my expected output I have followed two steps. in first step، I have weighted year 2 in each iteration by `wtd.table(df$iteration1$year2$district,weights=df$iteration1$year2$weight)` . I repeated this code for three times (because I have three iterations). here is my output:

```
  1    2    3    4 
25.3 23.5 11.2 10.1 
 1    2    3    4 
23.1 11.3 38.2 10.1  
1    2    3    4 
12.2 40.1 24.0 23.6
```

in second step, I calculate mean of each district for three iterations manually:  `mean(25.3,23.1,12.2)`

Comment: For what variable do you want to calculate the mean? How did you calculate your desired output?

Comment: @ wimpel please see my comments for @ronak shah

Comment: meanwhile that answer is deleted.. Please include your step-by-step manual calculation of the desired output (use edit). Right now it is not clear how/what your approach is (at least: it isn't to me ;-) )

Comment: Please give the additional information in your question. Do you always have three iterations and two years or is this somehow dynamic?

Comment: please see my update

Comment: @ martin Gal please see my update. it would be dynamic about 100 iterations and 5 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
library(questionr)
ans <- rbindlist(
  lapply(df, function(x) 
    as.data.table(
      questionr::wtd.table(x[["year2"]]$district, 
                           weights = x[["year2"]]$weight))),
  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
# Summarise
ans[, .(weight = mean(N, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(district = V1)]
#    district   weight
# 1:        1 20.20000
# 2:        2 24.96667
# 3:        3 24.46667
# 4:        4 14.60000
```

**Version 2**

With updated columns based on TS's comment below

```
ans <- rbindlist(
  lapply(df, function(x) 
    as.data.table(
      questionr::wtd.table(x = x[["year2"]]$district, 
                           y = x[["year2"]]$gender,
                           weights = x[["year2"]]$weight) ) ),
  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE )
# Summarise
ans[, .(n = .N,
        mean = mean(N, na.rm = TRUE),
        sd = sd(N, na.rm = TRUE)), 
    by = .(district = V1, gender = V2)]
#    district gender n      mean        sd
# 1:        1      1 3  8.433333 14.606962
# 2:        2      1 3  8.700000  7.582216
# 3:        3      1 3  7.466667  6.466323
# 4:        4      1 3 10.100000  0.000000
# 5:        1      2 3 11.766667 11.556095
# 6:        2      2 3 16.266667  8.602519
# 7:        3      2 3 17.000000  8.697126
# 8:        4      2 3  4.500000  7.794229
```

Comment: thanks a lot @wimpel it works. I  have one more question. how can I calculate confidence interval 95 ?

Comment: see **version 2** above

Comment: @ wimpel it is just standard deviation not confidence interval .95

Comment: Oh yeah... you can  change  the functions in the Summarise-part to your  needs.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the list of dataframes into one and calculate average weight using `questionr::wtd.table` for each `district` and iteration in year2.  Finally, get aggregated mean for each `district`.

Using `tidyverse` you can do -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map_df(df, ~bind_rows(.x, .id = 'year'), .id = 'iter') %>%
  filter(year == 'year2') %>%
  group_by(district, iter) %>%
  summarise(result = questionr::wtd.table(district,weights=weight)) %>%
  summarise(result = mean(result))

#  district result
#     <dbl>  <dbl>
#1        1   20.2
#2        2   25.0
#3        3   24.5
#4        4   14.6
```

Comment: thanks @Ronsk shah but it is not equal to my expected output

Comment: Ohh..I thought those were just dummy numbers. Can you explain your calculation for expected output. Reading your description again I think you need to calculate average for only `year2` which can be achieved with `map_df(df, ~bind_rows(.x, .id = 'year')) %>% filter(year == 'year2')  %>% group_by(district) %>% summarise(weight = mean(weight))` but this still doesn't give the same number as your expected output. How do you get `20.2` as average for first iteration?

Comment: firstly I have weighted district in year 2 for each iteration by `wtd.table` and then I calculate mean of each weighted district. my real data contain 100 iteration. if I use your first purposed code it takes lots of time.

Comment: Can you explain the calculation behind 20.2 for first district? How exactly do you calculate that?

Comment: I have calculate this manually because I did not know any function for doing that

Comment: thank you so much @Ronak shah but for 100 iterations combining the list into one data frame takes lots of time. is there any way?